Langchain function get_relevant_documents stops ECS Task Container
I have an application based on Langchain retriever and sometimes my ECS task stops giving an unhealthy check without any logs or errors, so I put some logs on my code and it stops right on calling get_relevant_documents.
I use AWS OpenSearch for vector retrieval and thought it may be a session timeout issue, but it doesn't seem to be the case.
It doesn't always occurs, but after some time of the container being up and running, it happens.
The get_relevant_documents function doesn't have any verbose or output logs so I have no idea what causes the issue.
Can anyone help me or have any clues as to what can be going on?
I tried refreshing the AWS session each time right before creating the retriever but it keeps on happenning.
